# How do I keep my program output from terminating and start the program again without losing the data?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, console-application

Okay so I may not have explained this very well but basically I wrote a menu based program with switch statements and I want the whole program to start again after one chooses a certain option and performs all the functionality in it.
Here is a code to give an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main() {
    string name;
    int num,age,cls;
    cout <<"Enter your name: ";
    cin>>name;
    cout <<"Enter your number: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"Enter your age: ";
    cin>>age;
    cout <<"Enter your class: ";
    cin>>cls;
    int choice;
    cout<<"\tPlease choose an option: "<<endl;
    cout <<"1. Display my name\n2. Display my number\n3. Display my age\n4. 
Display my class"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            cout<<"Your name is :"<<name;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout <<"Your number is: "<<num;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout <<"Your age is: "<<age;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout <<"Your class is: "<<cls;
            break;
        default:
            cout <<"Invalid option!";
            break;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

What do I do to keep the program from terminating at the end after an option is chose and instead display the whole menu again for another option to be chosen. Or the whole menu be displayed again after an invalid input is given and he default case executes.

Comment: Er. You'd use a loop?

Comment: Time to learn loops

Comment: No I heard there is a function that does this. I dont really know and thats what I was asking. Maybe it was getch(); or someother.

Comment: *"there is a function that does this"* - No, there isn't. How should any function know where to move back to and what to repeat? You have to write that code yourself

Comment: Not even to restart the whole program again?

Comment: No, because programs shouldn't be restarting themselves (in general). Also why would you rather restart the entire program than add a simple loop?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a while loop and support a menu option to exit the loop.

```
int main() {
    string name;
    int num,age,cls;
    cout <<"Enter your name: ";
    cin>>name;
    cout <<"Enter your number: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"Enter your age: ";
    cin>>age;
    cout <<"Enter your class: ";
    cin>>cls;

    int choice;

    bool exitRequested = false;
    while ( !exitRequested )
    {
        cout<<"\tPlease choose an option: "<<endl;
        cout <<"1. Display my name\n2. Display my number\n3. Display my age\n4. Display my class\n5. Exit program"<<endl;

        cin>>choice;
        switch (choice){
            case 1:
                cout<<"Your name is :"<<name;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout <<"Your number is: "<<num;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout <<"Your age is: "<<age;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout <<"Your class is: "<<cls;
                break;
            case 5:
                exitRequested = true;
                break;
            default:
                cout <<"Invalid option!";
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>*you can use a while loop with a counter variable for simplicity*
/int main() {
    string name;
    int num,age,cls;
    cout <<"Enter your name: ";
    cin>>name;
    cout <<"Enter your number: ";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"Enter your age: ";
    cin>>age;
    cout <<"Enter your class: ";
    cin>>cls;
    int choice,k=1;
while(k>0)
{
    cout<<"\tPlease choose an option: "<<endl;
    cout <<"1. Display my name\n2. Display my number\n3. Display my age\n4. 
Display my class"<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            cout<<"Your name is :"<<name;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout <<"Your number is: "<<num;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout <<"Your age is: "<<age;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout <<"Your class is: "<<cls;
            break;
        default:
            cout <<"Invalid option!";
            break;
    }
cout<<("do you want to renter the details and run again:\n");
cout<<("enter 1 for yes and o for no");
cin>>k;
}
   return 0;
}
```

>